# Couple issues with swipeable tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

I am trying to replicate Twitter's profile view on their app.

Here is a picture of the view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fsJB.png

There are 3 specific things I'm trying to achieve:

1. A header layout at the top of the view
2. A ListView below the header (on the Twitter app, this is the posts)
3. A ViewPager to swipe left and right (on the Twitter app, this is the tabs "Tweets", "Photos", and "Favorites"

I have #1 on the list done. Here is the header layout (`header.xml`):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

And I load it in my Fragment's `onCreateView()` method:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, listView, false);
    listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

    ...

    return view;
}
```

Here is my first Fragment, `fragment_one.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my main activity layout (`activity_main.xml`), I have this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
        app:pstsTabTextSize="14dp"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my Activity's `onCreate()` method looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

However, I have two issues:

1. The tabs aren't below the header as they should be.
2. When I swipe to go to another tab, the header also moves (even though it's the same header on all 3 Fragments). Here's a picture of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRArt.png

How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the header stationary by removing it from the views that are being swiped and placing it in a parent view, say a relative layout or frame layout, that contains your viewpager. Just be sure to add the header view AFTER you add the viewpager to your parent view.

Comment: The problem is that the header would then no longer move if I scrolled vertically since ListView is a scrollable view and the header wouldn't be scrollable.

Comment: You could use the OnScrollListener of the list view to hide the header view or do whatever when ever the user scrolls down the list. And to reappear when they get back to the top